# setInterval not working as expected with phonegap

Tags: javascript, jquery, geolocation, setinterval, phonegap-build

I have set up a function which checks the location of the user every X mins using `setInterval()` which works for the most part as expected.  However after some time of the phone being inactive the intervals seem to stretch out, ie if it was set to 5 mins it could take up to an hour to check again if the phone has been inactive for some time.  This is intended to keep going 24/7 so the phone being inactive will be common.

Is this a known problem or is there something I should be doing to prevent this?

```
var onDeviceReady = function(){
   var preCheckGPSInterval = setInterval(function(){
       var watchID = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(
           function(position){
               if(position.coords.accuracy < 100){
                   navigator.geolocation.clearWatch(watchID);
                   //code to execute
               }
           },
           function(error){
               console.log("error");
           },
           {enableHighAccuracy: true}
       );
   }, 300000);
}

document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
```

Comment: Try to keep the application in background, it doesn't solve your code problem, but resolves the action you want to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is this a known problem or is there something I should be doing to prevent this?

@Marty,
this is not a problem. This is the way it is supposed to work. If an App is NOT in the foreground, the app will have it's resources cleared from memory and possibly stored in swap space.

As suggested, you will need to force your app to run in the background. This article will help. [7 things you should know about Android Manifest xml file](http://gurushya.com/android-manifest/#sthash.PWfC4PRY.dpuf).

Comment: you wouldn't happen to know how to do that with phonegap build by any chance?

Comment: Yes. I have the answer. Please ask a new question so other may benefit when they search.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31974973/how-to-make-a-phonegap-build-app-work-in-background