# How to make a phonegap build app work in background

Tags: javascript, cordova, geolocation, setinterval, phonegap-build

I need my app to work 24/7 recording the users location every 5 mins.  It works fine while the phone is active but when it isn't the `setInterval()`'s strecth out to be up to 5x longer than they should.

Using phonegap build, how would I go about making the app work as it should in the background while the phone is idle?

Comment: Both Android and iOS severely limit what apps are allowed to do when running in the background. If apps don't have a good reason to still be doing things in the background, they are typically terminated or given very low priority. Also, good lord; why do you need to track your users so closely?? I am alarmed.

Comment: It is an automated timesheet for farmers.  if they are not at home + within the farm it records them as working.

Comment: Only way use native code. In Android, when app is background then js code not execute. In IOS then js code can call from native code to js via javascript interface. I think you should focus build background service from native

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Marty,
both Android and iOS and run in the background, but require an extension to the regular config.xml.

To be clear Android apps uses AndriodManifest.xml.
iOS uses, preferences.plist

Both have the ability to go into background. However, in Cordova/Phonegap this is not available directly, you must make an extension. The best explaination are from Cordova and Phonegap Build.

From Phonegap Build:
Start with: [Config File Elements](http://docs.build.phonegap.com/en_US/configuring_config_file_element.md.html#Config%20File%20Elements). You will need to add `<gap:config-file>` one for each, then you will also need to add to the first xml element, like this:

```
 <widget xmlns = "http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
        xmlns:android   = "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:gap   = "http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0"
        id          = "com.bsdmasterindex.googlemapexamples"
        version     = "1.0.0"
        versionCode = "10" >
```

The most important item being `xmlns:android   = "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"`. This is only for android, of course.

Examples of using this are in my Demo Boiler plates for Phonegap Build - source available at git hub.

[Three (3) Phonegap Build Boilerplates for For Android and iO](http://codesnippets.altervista.org/blog/2015/BLOG.2015-06-19.codesnippets.html)

You will want to look at Boilerplate #2.

This article will help.
[7 things you should know about Android Manifest xml file](http://gurushya.com/android-manifest/)

If you have further question, I suggest you go to [google groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/phonegap). I will soon be dropping Stackoverflow from my readying list. I willl likely drop on Monday.

Jesse

Comment: Thanks for that, but I don't get how I connect my js function from the manifest? can't find anything about that on any of the links

Comment: @Marty.H, There is no Javascript you do. You simply add the appropriate lines in your config.xml and the app is supposed to be able to run in the background. Read the docs (Android & iOS), they work differently, but they both do what you want - run your app in the background. In other words, you are telling both OSs, "please run my app in the background, and not the normal process".

Comment: I have been reading here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/service-element.html and it says I need to add the name of my service to the manifest, but I don't actually have a service to name, how do I get around that?

Comment: Okay. I can see you have not done any Android programming on that level. `config.xml` is a declarative structure, so is  `AndroidManifest.xml`.  With this task, you are "extending" config.xml. In fact, config.xml will become AndroidManifest.xml - in the end. I need to find my examples, I'll get back to this in a few hours.

Comment: Okay: instead, here is your Google lookup: [androidmanifest.xml declare background service](https://www.google.com/search?q=androidmanifest.xml+declare+background+service) If this is not enough, let me know.

Comment: I have not done any android programming what so ever.  by the looks of the articles you pointed me to that is something i'm going to have to learn right?

Comment: Of course, yes, you have to READ this. What did you expect? Background operations is NOT normal programming for phonegap. It is an exception. This is often know as the *one-off* rule.

Comment: Sorry, I misinterpreted your comment where you said "You simply add the appropriate lines in your config.xml and the app is supposed to be able to run in the background.". I had figured this was the case before that comment.  Didn't realize it was so rare.

Comment: @Marty .H, Android is fairly well designed, better than most mobile OS. However, it has to use a truely crappy language known as Java.